# Passing data to dynamic CSS file?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, cross-browser, less

This is more a question of what browsers will do, rather than the back-end architecture.

I am using **codeigniter** and have a controller setup to handle assets (CSS, JS, and images), and at the moment I am simply processing the PHP out of CSS files and presenting them as CSS files to the browser, so `www.mysite.com/asset/home.css` will call the asset class and generate the CSS file for home from a single file.

I would like to make the request for the CSS files more dynamic, so that the request will determine multiple files that should be combined, and then passed to `less.php` for parsing and minimization.

Taking into account issues of caching, what would be the best method of passing variables to the CSS class? Flat Link URI variables? Traditional GET URI?  I could use a database to reference a given name for its components, but isn't that a lot of overhead?

Any thoughts or opinions are welcomed!

++ How would browsers handle something like `standard.menu.comments.css`?

+++ I ended up going with a URI string appended to the file.  It's not as clean I would want, but it appears to be working.  I will likely move to a flat slash separated URI parser soon to clean up the request lines.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Like you said a major issue with this will be caching. Browsers like to cache things like your CSS files to make things happen quicker for the user. Using dynamic stylesheets may lead to unwanted results. Just a warning.

Comment: I haven't used codeigniter, but if you can change the code that links the stylesheet, you can fight client-side caching with the random query trick: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?r=<?php echo rand(); ?>">`

Comment: I'm not necessarily opposed to caching, I just want to make sure that if I append a URI, that the browser includes that as part of the cache title for css files. So that `home.css?page=comments` isn't considered the same as `home.css?page=video`.

Comment: @anstosa that'll kill all caching, which is probably not ideal

Comment: @Prescott not ideal, but sometimes necessary since some browsers (Chrome) don't actually obey expiry headers anymore... However the fact that the strategy works means that yes, BayssMenkanique, those two resources will be considered unique.

Comment: @anstosa That is exactly what I was trying to figure out.  I have no issue caching on my side, but I wasn't sure how browsers would accept the uri string.

Comment: I didn't realize chrome ignored expiry headers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a file `style.php` with the following header:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

And link this style in your template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.php?color=red">
```

Then you can import some stylesheets in your `style.php`:

```
@import ("someStyle.css");
```

Or you can pass some `$_GET` variables and create conditional styles:

```
<?php 
    if ($_GET['color'] == 'red')
    {
        echo ".myBlock {background: #ff0000;}";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo ".myBlock {background: #00ff00;}";
    }
?>
```

If you just don't want your `.css` files to be cached, append random $_GET variable to your linked style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

Comment: Like I said, the issue isn't with creating the file. It's figuring out how to best pass the data.  Are you suggesting that GET would be the best way to still cache?

Comment: It is the only way to create **dynamic** stylesheet. CSS itself is static. The best way to load appropriate styles is using individual `.css` files and loading them where needed.

Comment: Basically, that's all right, if you load `.css` with some unnecessary classes. No need to create separate `.css` for each and every page.

Comment: There is certainly more than one method for creating them, I'm just looking for the most browser friendly.  The method you recommend calls a .php file, which works fine in Moz & WK, but breaks in IE.  I'm thinking GET is going to be the best method.

Comment: My method using `$_GET`. The point is that you just **can't** receive variable in **.css** file. Maybe you'll find some use in LESS or SASS javascript libraries, which allows you to create dynamic layouts and compile them into `.css` in the end.

Comment: By the way, what's wrong with IE? Which version you use and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The newer version of IE(9) does not send `Accept: text/css; */*` but rather `Accept: text/css;`, so Apache responds with a 406 Error, since it doesn't know what to do with the php file.  You have to request it as a .css file, and either force Apache to process .css files, or accept as a URI variable and compose the file from there (as I am doing).

Comment: @BayssMekanique One more suggestion is to use `.htaccess` rewrite to parse `$_GET` variable to load the appropriate stylesheet file.

Comment: I think this does not working, because php just run at the files that have .php extention. and link can't work with php